# Is it possible to determine emission shader value by other lights?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, light, shaders

Is it possible to take a lamp/sun/point light and use it as a value on the scene to tell materials that are not affected by the light source to emit their own light?

[image]

This is photoshopped example of effect that I want to achieve. Ball + particles with diff/emit shader is lit from left by sun, the darker it becomes, the more light is emitted from particles.

Comment: If you want to drive the material emission strength with light emission strength then yes. Drivers can do this. Can you clarify the question a bit please? If you want to determine which materials are illuminated by lights and which not, then no. You would have to bake a lightmap and influence the materials with this map in a second pass render.

Comment: ! (http://i.imgur.com/XirQMPd.jpg) This is photoshopped example of effect that I want to achieve. Ball + particles with diff/emit shader is lit from left by sun, the darker it becomes, the more light is emitted from particles.

Comment: That looks like a transmittive material.

Comment: If you would call shader that is reacting to light rays like that, then it is indeed. Can it be build using nodes/drivers though?